# how to get Inline block to start on new line

Tags: html, css, block, inline, display

I have a group of inline blocks and I want after the 4th one for it to start on a new line. That's my project so far, kinda new to CSS so any helps is amaze thnx!

https://codepen.io/lumin-little/pen/poJpOMN

**HTML part**

```html
<div class="item-showcase">
    <article class="showcase">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1583803163205-847ab09b42fe?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80.jpg" id="puppo">
        </div>
        <h3>Example text #1</h3>
    </article>
    <div class="showcase">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1583803163205-847ab09b42fe?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80.jpg" id="puppo">
        </div>
        <h3>Example text #2</h3>
    </div>
    <article class="showcase">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1583803163205-847ab09b42fe?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80.jpg" id="puppo">
        </div>
        <h3>Example text #3</h3>
    </article>
    <article class="showcase">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1583803163205-847ab09b42fe?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80.jpg" id="puppo">
        </div>
        <h3>Example text #4</h3>
    </article>
    <article class="showcase">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1583803163205-847ab09b42fe?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80.jpg" id="puppo">
        </div>
        <h3>Example text #5</h3>
    </article>
    <article class="showcase">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1583803163205-847ab09b42fe?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80.jpg" id="puppo">
        </div>
        <h3>Example text #6</h3>
    </article>
</div>
```

**CSS part**

```css
.item-showcase
{
  padding-top:50px;
  padding-left:100px;
}

.showcase
{
  display:inline-block;
  background:red;
  padding:20px 20px 80px 20px;
}

#puppo
{
  width:250px;
  height:200px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.showcase:nth-child(4n) 
{
  background:green;
}
```

Thank you all and have a good night

Comment: consider to use flexbox

Comment: Sounds more like a job for Grid than inline-block

Comment: Could do something like `.item-showcase:nth-child(4n-1)::after{display: block; content: '';}` or similar?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use `display: flex` and add `width` property to the `.item-showcase` class. Your blocks have 290px width, so the width of .item-showcase should be **1180px (1160px + 20px)**, content plus elements margins.

```
.item-showcase
{
  width: 1180px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-top:50px;
  margin-left:95px;
}
.showcase
{  
  background:red;
  padding:20px 20px 80px 20px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
#puppo
{
  width:250px;
    height:200px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.showcase:nth-child(4)
{
  background:green; 
}
```

But if you want to use inline-blocks the width of `.item-showcase` should be **1172px (1160px + 12px)**, please keep in mind that inline-block is treated as an inline element, so the browser adds 4px as margins to every inline-block element.

If you want to add margins to the `.showcase` explicitly, you should delete whitespaces in your HTML between child elements.

CSS:

```
.item-showcase {
  width: 1172px;
  padding-top:50px;
  padding-left:100px;
}
.showcase {
  display:inline-block;
  background:red;
  padding:20px 20px 80px 20px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would help add a width in

```
.item-showcase
{ 
  width: 50%;       
  margin-top:50px;
  margin-left:95px;
}
.showcase
{
  display:inline-block;
  background:red;
  padding:20px 20px 80px 20px;
}
#puppo
{
  width:250px;
    height:200px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use a flexbox layout to achieve this.

```
 .item-showcase
{
  padding-top: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: space-between;
}
.showcase
{
  display: block;
  background: red;
  width: 25%;
}
```

You'll have to play around a bit if you want to get gutters (aka space between the blocks).

Basically, on the parent element you tell it to align its children in a row, and to "wrap" them if they exceed its width. On the children, you tell them to take 25% of the parent.

By the way, these two educational games are excellent to learn flexbox and grid: 
http://flexboxfroggy.com/
https://codepip.com/games/grid-garden/